# How to give expression for the details band based on the return value from subreport of the same band?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using iReports 4.7.1

I have 2 sub reports in my main report and they are in saperate bands. I need to hide the band if sub report returns no rows. I am able to get subreport value in my main report. But if i use that variable as a expression in the same band the value of that variable is becoming null, If i use that same variable in other details band, it is not becoming null.

I have two question to ask,

1. Why the value is becoming null if i use in same band?
2. Is their any other way to hide subreport returns no rows?

I followed [this](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/526978/hide-band-if-sub-report-returns-0-rows) steps to create variable and return value from subreport to main report.

And also i tried this **new Boolean($V{SUB_REPORT_ROW_CNT}.intValue()!=0)** or **$V{SUB_REPORT_ROW_CNT} != null**  expression in print when expression for the band.

Answer (score 0):

*Why the value is becoming null if i use in same band?*

I need to see jrxml but probably you do not have correct [EvaluationTime](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html) on the textField, try to set `Band` or `Report` example `evaluationTime="Report"` on the textField.

*Is their any other way to hide subreport returns no rows?*

The normal way to remove an empty subreport is by setting `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` on the `reportElement` of the subreport.

Make sure your **subreport** return **no page** (empty) when no data by setting the  `whenNoDataType="NoPages"` (or removing this attribute since this default) on the `jasperReport` tag

This will remove the subreport, note however if you like text under it to move you need to set  `positionType="Float"`, otherwise they will remain where they are since default is `positionType="FixRelativeToTop"`

Comment: Hi petter, Thanks a lot for your reply. for the first question about which text field you are talking. Actually in my subreport i am displaying image(image will be from db) and in main report i m not displaying the variable value. So for which text field i need to give evaluation time?

Comment: Also i tried the steps what you answered for my second question still the result is failed.

Comment: I imagine in first question, that you put the $V{SUB_REPORT_ROW_CNT} in a text field to see it... (in on this textField you need to set it).

Comment: @user3778890 Time that you edit the question, include the jrxml where you call subreport, include some screen shoot of current output creating a [mcve]. The suggested method works, I could pass screen shot's (but not related to your question so in answer it seems to have little sense)