# How to float text field if condition not leaving empty space?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report in jasper that look like:

```
sub total: (text) XX (formula)
disc: (text) xx (formula)
disc2: (text) xx (formula)
total: (text) xx (formula)
```

The value of discount `disc` and `disc2` may be often zero, and if so, I need to display it like:

```
sub total: (text) xx (formula)
total: (text) xx (formula)
```

How do I do in Jasper ireport?

[image: report picture]

The goal is to hide disc I and II line when it is 0 value, making the total line float up, without leaving the empty space.

Complete jrxml code: http://pastebin.com/Wuu82vJT

Comment: Where is your problem? Can you post your jrxml file?

Comment: @Jackie Possible duplicate of [JasperReports / iReport Designer: Can i show a band conditionally](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17524212/876298) & [How to give expression for the details band based on the return value from subreport of the same band](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35293689/876298). The same idea

Comment: @Jackie is this question still open? are you still having troubles?

Answer (score 4):

To **hide and remove** `reportElement` on value use the `printWhenExpression` and `isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"` (on all the textFields that needs to be removed)

**Example**

```
<textField pattern="#,##0;-#,##0" isBlankWhenNull="false">
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="453" y="22" width="97" height="16" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="e3279093-5beb-490a-9954-aad866ed208c">
        <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{vdisc_1}!=null&&$V{vdisc_1}.equals(0)]]></printWhenExpression>
    </reportElement>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Top">
        <font size="9"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{vdisc_1}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

To make a `reportElement` (total line) **float** up, use the `positionType="Float"` attribute

**Example**

```
<staticText>
   <reportElement positionType="Float" x="372" y="56" width="80" height="16" uuid="6ba40473-9efb-42e3-8b49-0d2c32ba84bd"/>
   <textElement>
      <font size="9"/>
   </textElement>
   <text><![CDATA[Total (Rp)]]></text>
</staticText>
```

without leaving the **empty space**, if textField float up naturally there is more space under and you can not simple set dynamic height of a band.

The easiest way to achieve dynamic height is to move all the text (in lastPageFooter) to a subreport (pass the data you need through parameters for example). Include this subreport with the minimum height and set its `positionType="FixRelativeToBottom"`

**Example**

```
<subreport>
    <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="0" y="87" width="555" height="41" uuid="656195bf-74bc-4aa0-9f0a-9c3a00cc6fb2"/>
    <subreportParameter name="vdisc_1">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$V{vdisc_1}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "example_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Comment: Does `isRemoveLineWhenBlank` work with frame elements? If I have a frame which is not printed some times and I want another frame below it to float up when the previous one is not printed... how could I do it?

Comment: @lealceldeiro Yes it should work, check it and then put a `printWhenExpression` (hence you need to not print it) + make sure elements that should float up have float as positionType, if it does not work pass a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: You were totally right. I made some [isolated tests](https://github.com/lealceldeiro/sample-element-float-up-jasper-report) and it works. It seems that I'm facing some problems in a bigger report (with a lot of components)

Comment: In [**this particular case**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52654844/5640649) it's not working as I expected. What could I do to overcome this? Thanks in advance for your valuable time.