# jasper reports move table to top if the above table is empty or null

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on creating a pdf file. I have 4 tables.

Here's the image. 
[image]
As you can see, **Table A** and **Table D** are empty tables. While, **Table B** and **Table C** are not empty. 
What I want is to move **Table C** to top (location of **Table A**). I tried "Remove lines when blank" and it worked. But, it will only work if **Table A** and **Table B** are empty.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Table C will not float since you have Table B above, use frames, reefer to this for more info https://stackoverflow.com/q/52654844/5292302

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to organize Frames in Jasper Report so they float flawlessly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52654844/how-to-organize-frames-in-jasper-report-so-they-float-flawlessly)